# Rvalue reference usage within initialization lists

Tags: rvalue-reference, c++11

I've been playing with Rvalue references lately and I've been experiencing a strange issue. Let's define some simple class named Foo that contains a `vector< int >`:

```
class Foo
{
public:

    Foo(std::vector< int >&& v)
        : v_(v)
    {}

private:

    std::vector< int > v_;
};
```

A `Foo` instance can be constructed by passing a `vector< int >` temporary like this:

```
std::vector< int > temp;
Foo(std::move(temp));
```

Now, when I tried to step through this code, I noticed that the vector inside `Foo` is constructed using the copy-constructor instead of the move-constructor. However, if I specify the constructor this way instead:

```
Foo(std::vector< int >&& v)
    : v_(std::move(v))
{}
```

Then, the move-constructor of the `v_` member is appropriately called. Why is that so? Why is the redundant `std::move(v)` necessary in the initialization list? Why is the compiler unable to deduce the intent to call the vector move-constructor since the corresponding `Foo` constructor argument is specified as a Rvalue reference?

By the way, I'm using GCC 4.6 with the -std=c++0x option.

Thanks for your help.
PMJ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside the function (or constructor) a named parameter is an lvalue, even if it is declared as an rvalue reference.

The rationale is something like

```
void foo(std::vector< int >&& v)
{
   bar(v);
   baz(v);
   boo(v);
   buz(v);
}
```

In which of these calls should the compiler consider moving from the object `v`?

None of them,  unless you do it explicitly.

Comment: So you can get the same effect (though with 1 more move constructor call) by simply taking the object by value. The caller uses `std::move`, and the constructor uses `std::move`. 2 constructors, but no allocations.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Thank you the clear answer. I had not thought about the issue arising from referencing the Rvalue argument multiple times.

@ Nicol Bolas: I'm not sure I understand your point, could you provide some example please? Thanks.